# jQuery: How to pass object context when object method called as callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, bind

I have an object:

```
var Person = function(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Hello" + this.name + ", " + this.age);
}
var sam = new Person("Sam", 31);
```

I want to call `Person.sayHello` as onclick callback and I found out that I can do it with bind method.

```
$("#button").on("click", Person.sayHello.bind(sam));
```

Maybe there is  more generic solution for it or some specific approach for jQuery to solve this problem at jQuery?

I need to add one note. I can have multiple instances of Person class and I want to make click to work for all of them. I thought about some loop over all Person instances and binding them to callback.

Comment: @vinayakj I will add it. I can create a lot of person instaces.

Comment: @vinayakj (a) that will call it immediately, instead of binding it as an event handler for later (b) it will only bind the function, without the context of the calling object.

Comment: @vinayakj then (b) still applies: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/MaqeMV (note "Hello, undefined" result)

Comment: `bind()` is about the best way to do it. you could use an anon+closure, but usually bind() solutions are simpler and more re-usable.

Comment: @vinayakj I thought about iterating over all `Persons` and put them into `bind`

Comment: you can replace `Person.sayHello.bind(sam)` with `bind(sam)` using `function bind(obj){return obj.sayHello.bind(obj);}` to cut down on over-repetitive code.

Comment: @dandavis Yes, but it not looks so explicit and clean :(

Comment: well, you can attach a binder to the instance to code it inline as `.on("click", sam.getHello() )`, where getHello() is like the bind() in my previous comment,  using `this` instead of `obj`

Comment: .bind is about as "clean" as you are going to get. Only other option would be an anonymous function that executes `sam.getHello()`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, you can use the [`jQuery.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) method, which is specifically made for attaching event handlers and keeps `this` intact. So, something like:

```
$('#button').on('click', $.proxy(sam, 'sayHello'));
```

However, if you're going to loop through a bunch on a single button click, you don't even need to worry about all that.

```
var sam = new Person("Sam", 31);
var bob = new Person("Bob", 32);
var pat = new Person("Pat", 33);
var people = [sam,bob,pat];
$('#button').on('click', function () {
    people.forEach(function (person) {
        person.sayHello();
    });
});
```

That assumes a relatively recent browser that supports [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Basically, those `People` objects already know what they're doing.

If you need to support older browsers change that `forEach` to:

```
$.each(people, function (i, person) {
    person.sayHello();
});
```

Thanks to [@dandavis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317490/dandavis) for the tip.

Comment: you can use $.each and change the callback parameters to `(i, person)` to ensure IE8 compat...